# Top 3 Max Score for each section SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

I looked at the other questions related to this but it did not work. I even played around with `Dense_Rank` and still couldn't get the right answer.

Using the Oracle Student Scheme Data. I am trying to find the highest 3 grades for each section based on two tables ( NOT the top 3 rows for each sections. )
This is based off the `Student` and the `Grade` table from the `Student` Scheme
I am using the Oracle Developer 10 and it does not look like it takes the `LIMIT` function. Cause it gives me the error

> missing right parenthesis

```
select 
g.SECTION_ID,g.NUMERIC_GRADE, s.First_Name,s.Last_Name
from GRADE g Join Student s
On g.student_ID = s.student_ID
and Grade_Type_Code='MT'
Where numeric_grade in(Select distinct numeric_grade
from grade 
order by numeric_grade desc limit 3);
```

Comment: Why do you tag three different rdbms if you use oracle?

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL-Server and mySql?

Comment: I'm guessing this is MySQL as you have a `LIMIT` clause in there, that certainly won't work in SQL Server.

Comment: No he's using Oracle, because he tried `LIMIT` and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROWNUM in Oracle:

```
SELECT g.SECTION_ID,
       g.NUMERIC_GRADE, 
       s.First_Name,
       s.Last_Name
  FROM grade g 
  JOIN Student s
    ON g.student_ID = s.student_ID
   AND Grade_Type_Code='MT'
 WHERE numeric_grade in (SELECT numeric_grade
                           FROM (SELECT DISTINCT numeric_grade
                                   FROM grade 
                               ORDER BY numeric_grade desc)
                   WHERE ROWNUM <=3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it's not correct. When I run it it only give me 1 grade from each section and the grade was 99  for all.    I want to see the Max 3 grades for each Section ( This would be considered a group?)

Comment: no problem, your question was not clear, I just modified your original code with limit to get the same results in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Solution with dense_rank:

```
select section_id, numeric_grade, first_name, last_name 
  from (
    select g.section_id, g.numeric_grade, s.First_Name,s.Last_Name,
        dense_rank() over (partition by g.section_id 
          order by g.numeric_grade desc) rnk
      from GRADE g 
        join Student s on g.student_ID = s.student_ID 
          and Grade_Type_Code='MT' )
  where rnk < 4
  order by section_id, numeric_grade desc
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e71b0/1)

Comment: you are a genius!  I had this solution with the dense_rank however, the placement of the "from GRADE g 
        join Student s on g.student_ID = s.student_ID 
          and Grade_Type_Code='MT' " was in the in wrong location when I tested it.  Thanks alot!